# How to Edit Background Size?

Tags: html, css, background

I have never coded in my life. I am a complete noob.
I have this HTML code, it's a countdown timer.

I wanted to change the background colour, which I did.
What I don't know how to do is change the size of the background so that it fits nicely around the text, rather than taking up the whole page.
How can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #ffd;
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Aug 17, 2017 00:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 

60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + ": " + hours + ": "
    + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "END";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by wrapping a `div` around your `p`

```css
.background {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
<p>
Hello world
</p>
</div>
```

Or even simply giving your `p` a background color. Like this:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<p>
Hello world
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you want to size your background with 1080px by 720px just add this in your css:

```css
body{
  background-size: 1080px 720px;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your CSS has an Error because you don't close the bracket after body. If you want to apply the Background to your text, just give the `<p>` Tag the background color:

*Edit: I changed your font-size a bit, since this was really huge. Just set it back to 15 if desired*

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Aug 17, 2017 00:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + ": " + hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "END";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  /* Empty body style, but with closed bracket! */
}

p {
  background-color: #ffd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Q1. I have made it at center by taking one parent div.
For your Q2. I have written media query. So if device is mobile it will use font as 1em.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .parent-div {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #demo {
      font-size: 2em;
      background: orange;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      #demo {
        font-size: 1em;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>

  <script>

    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Aug 17, 2017 00:00:00").getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 *

        60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + ": " + hours + ": " +
        minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";

      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "END";
      }
    }, 1000);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Two more noob questions: 1. how do I ensure that the whole thing remains in the center of the page? Right now it's at the left. I tried playing with "display", and I can get the text to center but the whole background stretches to the entire page. 2. Also, is there a way to make the timer scale depending on the size of its screen? It looks fine on a desktop but when viewed on a mobile device the text gets jumbled up.

Comment: @j919315 I have edited above post. Have a look in it and check if it is working fine.